# NodeJS - Cannot read proprety

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
var sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${user}`
  connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (rows[0].id == user) {
      console.log("Row exists.")
    }else {
      console.log("Row not exists.")
    }
  });
```

The problem is that if the given record in the table does not exist, an error pops up and the nodejs down. If the record exists in the table, everything is fine.

I get error: Cannot read property 'id' or undefined.

How to fix it?

Comment: If the record does not exist then i guess you need to define an error particularly for that. Something like `if(rows[0].id != user){console.log("Row not exists")}`

Comment: It doesn't work again. Only if id matches the variable, no error pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but you may want to test if rows is defined (if the error message is something like "cannot read id of undefiened") eg.:

EDIT: rows return an array so check for an empty array as follows:

```
  connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (rows.length == 0) {
    console.log('No rows found');
    return;
  }
  if (rows[0].id == user) {
    console.log("Row exists.")
  } else {
    console.log("Row not exists.")
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem :/

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? What was the problem? If the rows property always return an array then maybe check for `rows.length == 0`

Comment: Ah great I just change it in the answer, and you can mark it as true?